# How to show custom model parameter in rendering variant

Tags: sxa

I would like to show the custom model value in the rendering variant. Could someone assist with this?

In our scenario, we are getting the URL in the custom model property and would like to show this property value in an anchor tag in the rendering variant for the existing field "title".

I have found the Model option to have the rendering variant show the custom property. However, my question then is how can I bind its value to the anchor tag field in the rendering variant?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below link to show custom model parameter in rendering variant.

https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2019/03/external-model-data-SXA-variant-Sitecore.html

It is not the exact one that you want, but you can take idea from this.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Although I like the fact that people refer you to my blog (https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2019/03/external-model-data-SXA-variant-Sitecore.html) I'm not sure it will get you what you want.

I think you have 2 options:

- Use the example from the blog but make sure the entire output as you need it is being exposed from your model (so that you don't need to add it to an anchor tag anymore)
- use **Scriban** if you can. As I mentioned in https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2019/11/sitecore-sxa-93-scriban.html Scriban solved the issue of not being able to add Model data inside html constructions by exposing the `o_model` object (as also mentioned on https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/103/sitecore-experience-accelerator/the-embedded-items-and-objects-in-the-scriban-context.html)